# Win32 UI Control notification events

Tags: winapi

Automation API allows to hook some events on Win32 UI controls. 
How can I do the same with Win32 Calls from C# code?

thanks

Comment: Let's say we have a list control. Automation API can provide a notification callback for Structure Control change. This callback is called whenever any new item added or removed from item list.
Is there a way to do the same using Win32 calls? Some kind of hook that can be attached to the control that gets called whenever something changed

Comment: [UI Automation is also available in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).